# Show that for all $n$ there exist some $n$-digit number with no $0$ in it whose digit sum divides it.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, divisibility, decimal-expansion

$\textbf{Question:}$Prove that for each positive integer $n$, there exists a positive integer with the following
properties:

• it has exactly $n$ digits,

• none of the digits is $0$,

• it is divisible by the sum of its digits.

I tried for small values of $n$.For example, for $n=1,2,3$ I found  $1,12,132$ works.I tried few other ones.Tried to spot any pattern but failed.After that I tried few more things  but in vain.

Here digits are in decimal representation of $n$.Any kind of hint or full solution is appreciated.

Comment: Numbers divisible by the sum of their digits are known as harshad numbers.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang But Harshad numbers need not have exactly $n$ digits.

Comment: I saw this problem in "The IMO Compendium" page 293 (Shortlisted Problems).
Link: https://books.google.co.uz/books?id=okx0d9jdM8oC&pg=PA293&lpg=PA293&dq=Prove+that+for+each+positive+integer+n,+there+exists+a+positive+integer+with+the+following+properties&source=bl&ots=ZAjpK7I2Xa&sig=ACfU3U1jlxManhRuZYuxs6twyx6kZQxCKw&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjG3YbAm7TqAhUxw8QBHRrfDU8Q6AEwAHoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=Prove%20that%20for%20each%20positive%20integer%20n%2C%20there%20exists%20a%20positive%20integer%20with%20the%20following%20properties&f=false

Comment: And of course, [Kalva has solutions to several shortlist problems](https://prase.cz/kalva/short/soln/sh98n7.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's a classical induction problem to show that

> **Lemma.** Given $m\ge 1$, there is an $m-$digit multiple of $2^m$ whose digits are all $1$ or $2$.

Let $2^{m-1}\le n<2^m$ and $x$ be the $(m+1)-$digit multiple of $2^{m+1}$ given by the lemma. Notice the sum of digits of $x$ lies between $m+1$ and $2(m+1)$, therefore, we can choose the $n-(m+1)$ first digits of an $n-$digit number ending in $a$ so that its sum of digits equals any value from $\underline{n-(m+1)}+\underline{2(m+1)} = n+m+1$ to $\underline{9(n-(m+1))}+\underline{m+1} = 9n-8(m+1)$.

Now its easy to see that, for big enough $n$ ($n\ge 6$ should work), we have $$\underbrace{n+m+1}_{\approx n}\le \underbrace{2^{m+1}}_{\approx 4n}\le \underbrace{9n-8(m+1)}_{\approx 9n}$$
and, of course, $2^{m+1}$ divides any number ending in $x$, so the problem is solved!

For small values of $n$, just take any number whose sum of digits is $9$.